# Possible to prevent Eclipse automatically opening new files?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, workspace

Is it possible to prevent Eclipse from spawning a new tab and opening up a newly created file?
I am on a low end machine developing for Android, and find it very abrasive that every new layout xml I create automatically opens the layout manager in a new tab. I would rather the file just be created in the package explorer and if I need to open the new tab, then I can double click it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy/paste an existing file. That way you get a "new file" which will not be opened automatically.